# Django serialization to JSON error: 'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'concrete_model'

Tags: django, json, mongodb, serialization

I am working on an application that uses Django and MongoDB (as a model). I am trying to initialize (by hand) a model object (in order to send it further to another server), using the data got from a form. The model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(DynamicDocument):
    study_name = StringField(default="first study")
    individual_name = StringField(default="individual")
    file_list = ListField(StringField)   # this is a list of paths to some files
```

In the form I am doing the following:

```
pilot_object = MyModel()
pilot_object.individual_name = self.data['individual_name']
pilot_object.study_name = self.data['study_name']
pilot_object.file_list = files_list #file paths (strings)
```

where self.data is the data received from the form.
Now I want to serialize to JSON this object (pilot_object) as described in the documentation:

```
data_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', [pilot_object, ])
```

but I get this error:

**'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'concrete_model'**

and the serialization fails.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same problem, and found out that it's because I'm using MongoEngine which have different QuerySet objects. Documentation here:http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope, and I stopped looking for a solution lately. :(

Comment: I think DRF's serialization can't work on `mongoengine`. Maybe you could try [django-rest-framework-mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine) or don't use DRF's serialization.

Comment: I had a similar problem and using [DocumentSerializer](https://pythonhosted.org/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/serializers/) from `rest_framewrok_mongoengine seralizers` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , for mongoengine documents use -- 'from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers' rather from rest_framework import serializers. And the serializer class should inherit DocumentSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have meta `{Inheritance:True}` then remove it. It is looking for concrete class which i think you haven't designed so no need for inheritance to be True anyhow. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the model class inherit from Document. You need to install "rest_framework_mongoengine" for proper serializing. Check this out for proper documentation https://pythonhosted.org/django-rest-framework-mongoengine

from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers
from .models import MyModel

class PostSerializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
class Meta:
model = MyModel
fields = "**all**"

Answer (score -1):

This is due to you're using an older version of django. Check the difference between [1.3](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/db/models/base.py) and [1.4](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/base.py), `concrete_model` is only available for 1.4 and higher.

Comment: I am using Django 1.6b4 (Latest Beta currently available) and have run into the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having same issue with Django 1.7.8 :(